# Where to place the word "even": 1) "I am amazed even you would choose the day ......" or 2) "I am amazed you would even choose the day ....."

Tags: adverbs, emphasis

The sentence is from a British drama "[Downton abbey](https://youtu.be/iK0mlAjDHuA?t=278)".

Two sisters are not getting along well. One is trying out new clothes and asking what others think of her clothes when her sister is sad about something. Here is the conversation:

> A: I suppose you disapprove.
>
> B: "Not especially, I'm just amazed that **even you** would choose the day after I learn the man I love is dead to try out a new fashion."

My question is about the position of the word **"even".** It is placed right before **"you"**. So, it  sounds like it emphasizes **"you"**. but she needs to emphasize **"the action"** (her trying out a new cloth) rather than her, doesn't she?

So, should it be **".....I'm just amazed that you would even choose the day after I learn the man I love is dead to try out a new fashion."**

Comment: that you would even do x and that you even would do x are not the same thing and both are right.

Comment: @Lambie, what is the difference between the two? Do they emphasize different parts of the sentence?

Comment: That you would even do that surprises me. That you even would do that surprises me. No, I guess they are the same. Sorry. :)

Comment: It's not called 'Downtown Abbey'.

Comment: @Lambie, not sure if you're joking about, but the point you are making is exactly right (although your first comment  might have got the word order wrong). Weren't you trying to say that, **"That even you would do X"** doesn't mean the same as, **"That you would even do X"**? If so, you're correct, so I don't see why you backed off in your second comment.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey, you are right. It's real name is [Mad Bonkers Drama Series That'll Make You Want to Throw Any Close-At-Hand Heavy Object at Your Telly](https://youtu.be/b87E3kamWOg)

Comment: **Even** _does_ emphasise **you**.  As you say, Mary and Edith do not get on, and Edith thinks Mary's action is callous _even_ by the standards of her normal behaviour.

Comment: No, actually, the word order I used was right for what I meant and they mean the same thing. I **did not mean**: even you. That is indeed another meaning.

Answer (score 3):

The meaning changes depending on where you put **even**.

> I'm just amazed that **even** you would choose the day after I learn the man I love is dead to try out a new fashion.

She is comparing you to other people, and indicating she might have expected more from you. She might not be amazed if other people chose that day to try out a new fashion, but she is amazed that you would also do the same.

> I'm just amazed that you would even choose the day after I learn the man I love is dead to try out a new fashion.

This has nothing to do with other people. Another way of saying it might be that she is amazed you would **go so far** as to choose the day...